# Create simple list in Lua from C API

Tags: c, lua

I am trying to implement `dir()` function in C able to run this lua code:

***02_dir.lua:***

```
local function init()
 for name, filetype, size in dir("Lang") do
   print(name, filetype, size)
 end 
end
```

`dir()` implement in C is written that way:

```
static int l_dir(lua_State *L) 
{
    lua_pushstring(L, "foo");
    lua_pushstring(L, "file");
    lua_pushnumber(L, 11);

   return 3;
}
```

I get this error on `for` line when running :

```
lua_pcall() failed: 02_dir.lua:2: attempt to call a string value
```

Comment: Include the line where you register `l_dir`.

Comment: dir should be an iterator function if called by this way,  return a table and use `pair`  will do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to handle the return value as a list, and it isn't a list in the sense you mean.

Update your Lua file to read:

```
-- Define a function
local function init()
    local name, filetype, size = dir("Lang")
    print(name, filetype, size)
end

-- call it :)
init()
```

Answer (score 0):

This task is fully described in the book of Roberto Ierusalimschy "Programming in Lua". Here's a link with full example and explanation -- https://www.lua.org/pil/29.1.html